# Notification icons, fully white on some devices, multicolored on others. Why?

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar

**My question is not about how to create white icons.**

**I'm just trying to understand WHEN, exactly, the automatic white filter kicks in.**

I've read notification icons, from Lollipop onwards, automatically become white 'silhouettes', so even if you use a multicolored image with `setSmallIcon`, any non-transparent part of it will turn fully white when displayed in the status bar.

And that's precisely what it actually does on every nexus/pixel emulator I start from android studio. Any android version, among 5, 6, 7, 8, does this.

But I actually didn't find out about this lollipop feature until recently, because all this time, and even now, by loading the exact same app on **real devices**, I always see the original multicolor image in the status bar. This happens on a samsung s5neo, on a huawei p8lite, and many others.

I asked my users, and apparently some see them white, some see them colored. Some with Oreo see them white, some with Oreo see them colored. It seems it also depends on which specific icons I use, because some users report they see, on the very same device, some of them white and some of them colored.

I use with `setSmallIcon` either my `ic_launcher`, so applying it from the resources, or `Icon` objects created from some Drawables I get from external sources.
And I use pixeled sprites of characters as icons, so when I say colored I don't mean a 'green thing', I mean a really colorful image.

My app **has sdk target 27**, it also uses some oreo functionalities.

So, what's going on? I read everywhere that it should do the silhouettes on ANY >=lollipop device, but that's obviously not all there is to know about it, and I want to understand better.
How can, for example, my oreo users, see multicolored images, set with setSmallIcon, if I have sdk target 27?
Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: if you're running your app on API 21 or more , only then it will show the colored icon in notification.

Comment: @nirmal Said behavior happens on android 5, 6, 7 and 8, all of them

Comment: yes API 21 or more is equivalent to android 5 , 6 , 7 and 8. see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: @nirmal Yes, I know. But starting from api 21, icons should be automatically converted to white color. Aren't you saying the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

Create your notification icon using white pixels plus the alpha channel, [as documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html), and you will get consistent results.

Some device manufacturers tinker with Android. For some, apparently, that tinkering includes supporting non-standard notification icons. You have no good way, ahead of time, of knowing exactly which devices (out of 10,000+ models) will have this behavior.

If a device manufacturer hires you to build an app, or wishes to license an app from you, you might inquire about their notification icon policy and make adjustments to take advantage of whatever they offer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if it's probably impossible to know exactly which devices, I'd be curious to see some examples.

In my case, multicolored icons actually work way better. So I'd like to understand how to detect the difference, so I can use the original multicolored images when possible, and expecially prepared silhouette ones otherwise.

Comment: @LukeB.: You already know some examples -- you listed them in your question. I am not certain what more you are seeking.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Is there a source for this answer, to verify that it is really due to the manufacturers' tinkering, or is it just your assumption based on personal experience? (Not saying that I won't trust your assumption, it sounds valid enough. Just gathering info.)

Comment: @LukeB.: "Is there a source for this answer" -- well, I doubt that any manufacturer has some Web page describing each of the changes that they made in their Android OS versions. "is it just your assumption based on personal experience?" -- there is no question that manufacturers tinker with Android. Thousands of questions and answers here on SO, and countless articles about manufacturer changes, stand as testament. With respect to notification icons, your question would seem to contain the evidence that you seek. So, again, I am not certain what more you want.